# How to use ua:// URLs

Tags: ios-appstore, url

There are buttons in the Starbucks app on iOS for redeeming free apps and if I long press on the button, it shows a URL like `ua://75A6A5DC-D3BE-4056-9482-CEBCD5493F98`. However, I don't know how to use the URL if I copy it. Safari won't navigate anywhere if I paste it in the address bar and press <kbd>Go</kbd>. If I just tap the button in the Starbucks app, it takes me to the App Store and automatically begins to redeem an app (presumably using a code embedded in, or retrieved from, the `ua://` URL, but I'm not sure on that—just my hypothesis).

I have Googled and can't find any information on the `ua` URI. Can someone link me to documentation on what it means and how to use links like that?

Comment: If I had to guess, I think that's Urban Airship's URL scheme.  Something must not be implemented properly on your device or the Starbucks app.  I'd reach out to their support team.

Comment: @JAL Let me clarify the question to explain more in-app behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button, iOS looks for an app that advertises itself as being able to handle `ua://`-URLs. Safari doesn't know how to do that, you'll need an app for that. I don't know if there's a way to find out which app responds to which URL schemes.
See [this developer article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001700-387826).

Comment: Let me clarify the question to explain more in-app behavior.